# Entity Framework database first, Views have more than one EntityKey

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

We are using entity framework 5/6 to generate a database first Model, to expose some views 
I noticed in the generated model, that many columns are defined as Keys (EntityKey = true) which made entity framewrok include order by statements in almost every query to that view.

I don't know the rule of thumb here, but through trial and error and monitoring the generated SQL queries in SQL profiler, I concluded that Entity Framwork adds order by to all the queries using the columns marked as Entity Keys.

```
  SELECT [ID]
        ,[Name] 
        ,[Phone]
        ,[Type]
 FROM myView
 ORDER BY [ID] ASC, [Name] ASC, [Type] ASC
```

If I modified the edmx file through dessigner and set EntityKey = false to Name and Type columns the query is:

```
  SELECT [ID]
        ,[Name] 
        ,[Phone]
        ,[Type]
 FROM myView
 ORDER BY [ID] ASC
```

The question is, how does Entity Framework decide that [ID],[Name], and [Type] are Entity Keys in the first place?

The Problem is, so many order by may affect performance, isn't that right?, and the [Name] column is of type XML, so SQL server simply throws exception

```
  The XML data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using the IS NULL operator.
```

Comment: aren't these columns primary keys in the database table? it is supposed to reflect the primary keys to be entity keys in the edmx

Comment: How can I make a column a Primary Key in a SQL view?